# Maximising area of a pentagon given a fixed perimeter

Tags: calculus

ABCDE is a pentagon of fixed perimeter P cm. Its shape is such that ABE is an equilateral triangle and BCDE is a rectangle. If the length of AB is x cm, find the value of P/x for which the area of the pentagon is the maximum.

This question is in a chapter dealing with calculus and maxima and minima. Someone posted a similar question but the answer offered used LaGrange multipliers, of which I know nothing.

I have drawn the following diagram.

[image]

I have said:

Area = ABE + BCDE

$= \frac{1}{2}x(x^2 - \frac{x^2}{4})^{1/2} + xy$

$P = 2y + 3x$

So $y = \frac{P - 3x}{2}$

I now have a formula for the area in terms of P and x:

Area = $\frac{1}{2}x(x^2 - \frac{x^2}{4})^{1/2} + x(\frac {P - 3x}{2})$

I have tried differentiating this but it becomes very messy and I am not sure I am on the right track. Can anyone help?
I am self-taught.

Comment: You should simplify your expression further before differentiating. $(x^2 - x^2/4)^{(1/2)} =\sqrt 3 x/2$, for instance.

Comment: Make it into a simple quadratic expression.

Comment: Thank you for these helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P = 3x + 2y \implies y = \frac{P - 3x}{2}$

Pentagon area $A = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{\sqrt3 x}{2} \times x + xy$

$A = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{\sqrt3 \, x}{2} \times x + x \times \frac{P - 3x}{2}$

At extrema, $\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{\sqrt3 \, x}{2} + \frac{P}{2} - 3x = 0$

That gives us $\frac{P}{x} = 6 - \sqrt 3$